# Multivariable Differentiabiltiy

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Using the definition: $\lim_{x\to a}$ ${\left\Vert f(x)-f(a)-T(x-a) \right\Vert \over \left\Vert x-a \right\Vert}$ where ${T(x-a)}$ is the matrix of partial derivatives ${Df_a}$, I'd like to show that the function
$$f(\vec{x}) = {x_1x_2^2\over x_1^2 + x_2^2} \text{ if } \vec{x}  \neq \vec 0,\quad f(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$$

is not differentiable at $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$

The only thing is, I'm confused as to what the matrix of partial derivatives should be in this case since I've just been given this function.

Or is it just enough to show that two different paths approaching the point a, produce different values (but at the same time I think a differentiable function can still have discontinuous partial derivatives so that doesn't really help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were, then the Jacobian is the zero matrix, and it amounts to see how the existence of the following limit leads to a contradiction:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{\dfrac{hk^{2}}{h^{2}+k^{2}}}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}=0.
\end{align*}
Let $k=h$, $h>0$, then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}h}\cdot\dfrac{h^{3}}{2h^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ne 0,
\end{align*}
here a contradiction.

Comment: Wait, I am checking now.

Comment: Oh I see. So, if the Jacobian gives the best linear approximation at a point, then why should a differentiable function have the zero Jacobian?

Comment: It is the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The Jacobian is $[1,0]$? Aren't those partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are still zero?

Comment: @user284331 ah yes, true (my bad)

Comment: Ya, you need to put $f(x_{1},0)$, no?

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(0,0)=\lim_{x_{1}\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x_{1},0)-f(0,0)}{x_{1}}=\lim_{x_{1}\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{0-0}{x_{1}}=0$.

Comment: Ya, you got to set $x_{2}=0$, because I am dealing with $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(0,0)$.

Comment: Okay I see the issue. The point is that, you tend to cancel up side down provided that $x_{2}\ne 0$, but we got to set $x_{2}=0$ at the very beginning.

Comment: You're right.  I'm having a brain cramp.  I've deleted my comments lest they confuse others.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Comment: @user284331 hey sorry, one more question; if we didn't know right away that it wasn't differentiable but we knew the jacobian was [0,0], meaning it has some sort of horizontal tangent plane existing, that wouldn't be enough to declare it *not* differentiable, right?

Comment: I am not convinced with that argument. First, how do you define horizontal tangent plane properly and how to deduce from here about the differentiability. Actually I am no geometer and for all these issues about differentiability I used to do it in an analytically way, so I can't answer you right at the moment.